# jQuery: dialogs not showing in front anymore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I get jQuery **dialogs** to show on front ?
It was happening by default with previous Jquery versions.

My dialogs now appear hidden behind other stuff.

I unsuccessfully tried to set z-index this way:
`$("<p>My Dialog</p>").dialog().css('z-index', 9999);`

Comment: What browser are you using & which version of jQuery do you have. http://jquery.com/download/ Version 2.x does NOT support IE 6,7&8.

Comment: Can you show your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Hello, Chrome and jQuery: both latest versions

Comment: You're setting the z-index on the original `<p>` element. jQuery UI will set up a `.ui-dialog` div which you could set the z-index for.

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/dialog-z-index-bug - Tells me stack:false will help.. More people have problems with that!

Comment: Hope this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917430/jquery-ui-1-10-dialog-and-z-index

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my weird issue adding this code:

```
$("<p>My Dialog</p>").dialog().parent().css('z-index', '');
```

I had to add `.parent()`